# I can't install Eve online for OS X

Tags: macos, eve-online

So here's the deal: in the official eve page, after creating my account and starting the trial version, when i click on the download button for mac, it downloads the file shown in the image: (3rd icon to the right)
[image]

But when I click on the icon, it says "Eve online error" and i have to "terminate" the program. I've enabled my mac to permit any app to access my computer but it still doesn't work! 
Any ideas?

Comment: Try downloading the full offline installer from here: http://content.eveonline.com/879797/eve-premium_010474_879797-mac.dmg and use that one. Make also sure you meet the minimum system requirements.

Answer (score 7):

This may be happening because you're trying to run EVE Online from the disk image you downloaded. Disk images are read-only, so it's possible that the app is trying to modify or update itself somehow, and the error message is the result. You'll have to copy the EVE Online app somewhere on your hard disk (like into your Applications folder) and run it from there.

I see from the screenshot that the disk image contains a handy shortcut to the Applications folder for your convenience, so you should just be able to drag it onto that icon to copy it. Once you do this, you should be able to to eject the disk and delete the disk image (.dmg file) you downloaded.

I just tested this out myself and got the same error message when running EVE Online from the disk image, but it worked once I copied it somewhere else first.

Answer (score 0):

I use Epic Game Launcher on my iMac and it works great.

Comment: This will very likely not help the OP, since there is no mention of EVE running through Epic.

Comment: I thought OP was trying to install Eve Online on OS X.  I guess you're saying using a launcher to install isn't installing.